# Getting NullPointerException in custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm getting errors like this when I run my app:

```
02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     
        at myPlanAdapter.getView(MyPlanActivity.java:145)
        02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    02-27 22:59:19.331: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
```

And my Source code is:

```
public class MyPlanActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,
        OnClickListener {
    private String TAG = "MyPlanActivity";
    private Button addButton = null;
    private ListView listView;
    myPlanAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewInit();
        adapter = new myPlanAdapter(getBaseContext());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    private void viewInit() {
        setContentView(R.layout.myplan);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddMyPlanButtonId);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListViewId);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.AddMyPlanButtonId:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddMyPlan.class));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView,
            int paramInt, long paramLong) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class myPlanAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyPlan> {
        Context context;
        MyPlanDataSource dataSource;

        public myPlanAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.myplan_list_view_entry);
            this.context = context;
            dataSource = new MyPlanDataSource(context);
        }

        private ArrayList<MyPlan> getAllPlan() {

            dataSource.open();
            ArrayList<MyPlan> allPlan = dataSource.getAllPlan();
            dataSource.close();
            Log.d(TAG,allPlan.get(0).getSubjectName());
            return allPlan;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.d(TAG,"Size: "+getAllPlan().size());
            return getAllPlan().size();
        }

        @Override
        public MyPlan getItem(int position) {
            return getAllPlan().get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myplan_list_view_entry, parent,
                        false);

                final PlanViewHolder viewHolder = new PlanViewHolder();

                viewHolder.subjectName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListSubNameTextViewId);
                viewHolder.targetGrade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListTargetGradeTextViewId);
                viewHolder.duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListDurationTextViewId);
                viewHolder.examDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListExamDateTextViewId);
                viewHolder.daysTogo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myplanListDaystogoBoardTextViewId);
                viewHolder.delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanDeleteImageViewId);
                Log.d(TAG, "" + position);

                row.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            final PlanViewHolder holder = (PlanViewHolder) row.getTag();


            holder.subjectName.setText((getAllPlan().get(position) 
                    .getSubjectName())); // line 145
            holder.targetGrade.setText("Grade : "
                    + getAllPlan().get(position).getTargetGrade());
            holder.duration.setText(getAllPlan().get(position).getExamTime());
            holder.examDate.setText(getAllPlan().get(position).getExamDate());



            holder.daysTogo.setText(getAllPlan().get(position).getDaysTogo());

            holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    builder.setTitle("DELETE")
                            .setMessage(
                                    "Are you sure you want to delete this Subject?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                        {

                                            dataSource.open();
                                            dataSource
                                                    .deletePlan(getItem(position));
                                            dataSource.close();
                                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("No",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                        {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();

                }
            });


            return row;
        }
    }

    static class PlanViewHolder {
        private TextView subjectName;
        private TextView targetGrade;
        private TextView duration;
        private TextView examDate;
        private TextView daysTogo;
        private ImageView delete;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try Using `this` instead of `getBaseContext()`.

Comment: reRun and Double click on your logcat error ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are searcing for your row views in the wrong place. Try to find them in your inflated row `view`(in the `getView()` method):

```
viewHolder.subjectName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myPlanListSubNameTextViewId);
viewHolder.targetGrade = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myPlanListTargetGradeTextViewId);
viewHolder.duration = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myPlanListDurationTextViewId);
viewHolder.examDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myPlanListExamDateTextViewId);
viewHolder.daysTogo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myplanListDaystogoBoardTextViewId);
viewHolder.delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanDeleteImageViewId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit on `ViewHolder` ids, you need to get these ids from `convertView(the view passed in)` like this:

```
viewHolder.subjectName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myPlanListSubNameTextViewId);
```

Do the same for others.

Answer (score 0):

Make these change to your `getView()` method:

```
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent)
        {
            final PlanViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myplan_list_view_entry, parent,
                        false);

                viewHolder = new PlanViewHolder();

                viewHolder.subjectName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListSubNameTextViewId);
                viewHolder.targetGrade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListTargetGradeTextViewId);
                viewHolder.duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListDurationTextViewId);
                viewHolder.examDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanListExamDateTextViewId);
                viewHolder.daysTogo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myplanListDaystogoBoardTextViewId);
                viewHolder.delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myPlanDeleteImageViewId);
                Log.d(TAG, "" + position);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else 
                viewHolder=(PlanViewHolder)convertView.getTag();   
         ... 
         return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the line you are getting the `NullPointerException`, you need to figure out what is `null`:

```
holder.subjectName.setText(
  (getAllPlan()
   .get(position)
   .getSubjectName()));
```

It could be the call to `getAllPlan()`, the `get(position)` or the `getSubjectName()`.

What type does the `getAllPlan()` method return? And are the keys in this type the same values as the positions in the list? By putting the code on different lines it is easier to spot where you get the null.

Also, `getAllPlan().get(position)` will return the same as `getItem(position)` in an `ArrayAdapter`.