# How can I get checkboxes working in my listview?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, custom-adapter

I've been trying to follow tutorials/ posts on S.O on how to get my `checkbox` working in my `listview`. Lots of stuff I want to do with it but first I want to simply get the position of the item checked but the app crashes and I get a `NullPointerException` error.

The error is (with more stuff below this part) :

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.SelectPhoneContactAdapter.getView(SelectPhoneContactAdapter.java:104)
```

And line 104 is :

```
convertView.setTag(v);
```

But to me it looks like I've been following the tutorials properly and I don't know how to adapt these posts to my problem: [Getting NullPointerException in custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468113/getting-nullpointerexception-in-custom-listview) and [Crash in ListView at AbsListView.obtainView for ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307688/crash-in-listview-at-abslistview-obtainview-for-listactivity). Can you tell me what is wrong? Everything worked well until I started experimenting with these checkboxes.

Here is my `customadapter` code, `SelectPhoneContactAdapter`:

```
public class SelectPhoneContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //define a list made out of SelectPhoneContacts and call it theContactsList
    public List<SelectPhoneContact> theContactsList;
    //define an array list made out of SelectContacts and call it arraylist
    private ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact> arraylist;
    boolean itemChecked[];
    Context _c;

    //define a ViewHolder to hold our name and number info, instead of constantly querying
    // findviewbyid. Makes the ListView run smoother
    ViewHolder v;

    public SelectPhoneContactAdapter(final List<SelectPhoneContact> selectPhoneContacts, Context context) {
        theContactsList = selectPhoneContacts;
        _c = context;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(theContactsList);
        itemChecked = new boolean[theContactsList.size()];

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("the amount in arraylist :" + arraylist.size());
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return theContactsList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

    static class ViewHolder {
        //        In each cell in the listview show the items you want to have
//        Having a ViewHolder caches our ids, instead of having to call and load each one again and again
        TextView title, phone;
        CheckBox check;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        //we're naming our convertView as view
        View view = convertView;


        if (view == null) {

            v = new ViewHolder();
            System.out.println("getview position :" + i);

            //if there is nothing there (if it's null) inflate the view with the layout
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.phone_inflate_listview, null);


            //      So, for example, title is cast to the name id, in phone_inflate_listview,
//        phone is cast to the id called no etc
            v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
            v.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

            convertView.setTag(v);

            //or else use the view (what we can see in each row) that is already there
        } else {
            view = convertView;

        }


//        store the holder with the view
        final SelectPhoneContact data = (SelectPhoneContact) theContactsList.get(i);

        //in the listview for contacts, set the name
        v.title.setText(data.getName());
        //in the listview for contacts, set the number
        v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());
        v.check.setChecked(false);

        v.check.setChecked(itemChecked[i]);

        v.check
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                 boolean isChecked) {
                        itemChecked[i] = isChecked;
                    }
                });

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return view;


    }
}
```

My getters and setters, `SelectPhoneContact`:

```
public class SelectPhoneContact {

    String phone;

    public String getPhone() {return phone;}

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Boolean selected;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected){
        this.selected=selected;
    }
}
```

I can post more code if necessary.

Comment: I didn't figure out the problem but, Is there specific reason you are using list view instead of recycler view? If not I advice you to have a look on recycler view and you may like to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ...
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        ...
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.phone_inflate_listview, null);
        ...
        convertView.setTag(v);
    }
    ...
}
```

First you assign the value of `convertView` to your `view` variable. When it is null, you branch into the `if` statement, where you assign a new value to `view` via `li.inflate()`.

However, you then reference `convertView` later inside this `if` statement. Despite the fact that you wrote `view = convertView` above, at this point `convertView` is still `null`.

There are two ways to fix this. The first option is to simply change `convertView.setTag(v)` to `view.setTag(v)`. The other is to delete this line:

```
View view = convertView;
```

And simply change any place you reference `view` to use `convertView` instead. There's no need to introduce a new `View view` variable; you can just work with `convertView` directly.